# Getting Received log message: <Google:HTML> Incorrect native ad response. Click actions were not properly specified.witht error code 0

Tags: java, android, kotlin, admob

I am trying to implement native ads. I am getting error code 0 and 3 on both test units and real units when trying on emulator. While checking the logs I found the following statement.

`Received log message: <Google:HTML> Incorrect native ad response. Click actions were not properly specified`

`Ad failed to load : 0`

Error code 0 is coming when I am using real Ad units.

I am trying to populate this native ad inside a FrameLayout.
Below is a code snippet from my xml file:

```
<LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/adLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/nativeAdArea"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:visibility="gone" />
               </LinearLayout>
```

Here's my java code snippet.

````
    FrameLayout nativeAdArea;
    nativeAdArea = findViewById(R.id.nativeAdArea);

    private void showNativeBanner() {
        AdLoader adLoader = new AdLoader.Builder(this, getResources().getString(R.string.admob_native_mainactivity))
                .forUnifiedNativeAd(new UnifiedNativeAd.OnUnifiedNativeAdLoadedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onUnifiedNativeAdLoaded(UnifiedNativeAd unifiedNativeAd) {
                        Log.e("nativead", "loaded");

                        // Show the ad.
                        nativeAdArea.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                        UnifiedNativeAdView adView = (UnifiedNativeAdView) getLayoutInflater()
                                .inflate(R.layout.layout_homepage_nativead, null);
                        // This method sets the text, images and the native ad, etc into the ad
                        // view.
                        mUnifiedNativeAd = populateUnifiedNativeAdView(unifiedNativeAd, adView);
                        nativeAdArea.removeAllViews();
                        nativeAdArea.addView(adView);
                    }
                })
                .withAdListener(new AdListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAdLoaded() {
                        super.onAdLoaded();
                        mUnifiedNativeAd.setOnPaidEventListener(new OnPaidEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onPaidEvent(AdValue adValue) {
                                Bundle params = new Bundle();
                                params.putString("valuemicros", String.valueOf(adValue.getValueMicros()));
                                params.putString("currency", adValue.getCurrencyCode());
                                params.putString("precision", String.valueOf(adValue.getPrecisionType()));
                                params.putString("adunitid", getResources().getString(R.string.admob_native_mainactivity));
                                params.putString("network", Objects.requireNonNull(mUnifiedNativeAd.getResponseInfo()).getMediationAdapterClassName());
                                AnalyticsManager.logEvent("paid_ad_impression", params);
                            }
                        });
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
                        Log.e("nativead", "failedtoload" + errorCode);
                        // Handle the failure by logging, altering the UI, and so on.
                        nativeAdArea.setVisibility(View.GONE);
//                        getSmaatoNativeAd();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAdClicked() {
                        if (mFirebaseAnalytics == null) {
                            mFirebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(NewMainActivity.this);
                        }
                        Bundle adClickAnalyticsbundle = new Bundle();
                        adClickAnalyticsbundle.putString("app_version", BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME);
                        adClickAnalyticsbundle.putString("type", "native");
                        adClickAnalyticsbundle.putString("ad_unit_name", "homepage_lower_native");
                        mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent("clicked_ad", adClickAnalyticsbundle);

                        Bundle abTestBundle = new Bundle();
                        abTestBundle.putString("app_version", BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME);
                        abTestBundle.putString("type", "native");
                        mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent("native_vs_adaptive", abTestBundle);
                    }

                })
                .withNativeAdOptions(new NativeAdOptions.Builder()
                        // Methods in the NativeAdOptions.Builder class can be
                        // used here to specify individual options settings.
                        .build())
                .build();

        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().addNetworkExtrasBundle(AdMobAdapter.class, extras)
                .build();
        runOnUiThread(() -> {
            adLoader.loadAd(adRequest);
        });
    }

    ```

[![Here's a snapshot of the log][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/f43d9.png
````

Comment: Consider adding your code that is leading to this error

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue and found another correct answer on this: [Flutter, Native Admob, Ad failed to load : 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67355780/flutter-native-admob-ad-failed-to-load-0)

You need to test your app with an emulator that has Google Play framework installed.

Comment: Nice, fixed my problem.

Answer (score 3):

I also faced same issue on emulator but when I tried same code on real device native ads seems to work perfectly.

Comment: Even after more than 6 months this is still the correct answer - the API answers with "Internal error." when requests are sent from the Android Emulator, but is working when used on a real device.