# Flutter, Native Admob, Ad failed to load : 0

Tags: flutter, admob, firebase-admob, google-mobile-ads

https://pub.dev/packages/google_mobile_ads

I copied this example

and everything is working fine except "Native Ad"

Of course, MainActivity.kt and NativeAdFactoryExample.kt are all set perfectly

and of course I used testAdUnitId for NativeAd

but it keeps show

```
I/Ads     ( 6932): Received log message: <Google:HTML> Incorrect native ad response. Click actions were not properly specified
I/Ads     ( 6932): Ad failed to load : 0
I/flutter ( 6932): NativeAd failedToLoad: LoadAdError(code: 0, domain: com.google.android.gms.ads, message: Internal error.)
```

I`m working on it for 12hours and it`s still not solved and I am really getting crazy

Could anyone help this problem please?

Answer (score 3):

If your code is OK, then nothing to worry about. just try again on other emulator with "google play" or try with live device.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

if your code is fine and also you are using an emulator with google play.
just set your app-ads.txt which can be found in your all apps on google AdMob

[image]

Google will crawl the URL (root URL of your website) and find these apps requesting or serving ads.

Answer (score 0):

So i came up against this and could not get it to work until i found this https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-flutter/issues/399 so making your ad widget use the auto keep alive mixin apparently helps, i tried that with my code and it would not work i then used the example in the link which did work, the only difference i can see is he is creating an instance of the ad in init state and then calling .load() on that instance, where as i was using the dart notation and creating the instance and calling ..load() in the same call Object()..load() i think these things are usually identical but i switched to his version and it worked. Below is the example the only i thing i swapped was the style from using the factoryId to specifying a style

```
      class NativeInlineAd extends StatefulWidget {
    const NativeInlineAd();
  
    @override
    State createState() => _NativeInlineAdState();
  }
  
  class _NativeInlineAdState extends State<NativeInlineAd>
      with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
    // COMPLETE: Add NativeAd instance
    late NativeAd _ad;
  
    // COMPLETE: Add _isAdLoaded
    bool _isAdLoaded = false;
  
    @override
    void initState() {
      super.initState();
  
      // COMPLETE: Create a NativeAd instance
      _ad = NativeAd(
        adUnitId: kReleaseMode
            ? '<YOUR_NATIVE_ADMOB_ID>'
            : '<NATIVE_TEST_AD_ID>',
        factoryId: 'googleNativeAdsCard',
        request: const AdRequest(),
        listener: NativeAdListener(
          onAdLoaded: (_) {
            setState(() {
              _isAdLoaded = true;
            });
          },
          onAdFailedToLoad: (ad, error) {
            // Releases an ad resource when it fails to load
            ad.dispose();
  
            throw 'Ad load failed (code=${error.code} message=${error.message})';
          },
        ),
      );
  
      // COMPLETE: Load an ad
      _ad.load();
    }
  
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      super.build(context);
      if (_isAdLoaded) {
        return Container(
          child:  SizedBox(height: 200, child: AdWidget(ad: _ad)),
          ),
          height: 270,
          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
            left: 10,
            right: 10,
            top: 5,
          ),
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
              ValuesConstant.borderRadius,
            ),
            border: Border.all(
              width: 1,
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
            color: Theme.of(context).cardTheme.color,
          ),
          alignment: Alignment.center,
        );
      }
      return const SizedBox(
        height: 72.0,
        child: Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(
            valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(
              Colors.grey,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
  
    @override
    void dispose() {
      _ad.dispose();
      super.dispose();
    }
  
    @override
    bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
  }
```